# Does tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits covert data into probabilities?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

In classification problems we prefer to apply `tf.nn.softmax` function because this function gives output as probabilities or we can also implement `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` which apply softmax activation function on model's output. I want to classify my data into two classses. I came across a code where they used `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` at the last Layer. I want to know that can we use sigmoid as an activation function at the last layer? Shouldn't we use softmax? Without applying softmax how can I know probabilities? Because at the end of the model when we check how accurate is our model we use following command

```
tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,axis=1),tf.argmax(y_,axis=1))
```

Can after using sigmoid at the last fully connected layer we can use above command for checking correct predictions?

Answer (score 1):

The code that uses `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` is not doing multi-class classification, it is doing **multi-label classific**ation, where you have multiple classes, but these are not exclusive and multiple classes might be predicted at the same time.

For the multi-label case, sigmoid is preferable as then you get an independent probability for each class. Evaluation in this case is different, you can't use plain accuracy and precision/recall for each class is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Softmax is used to convert the raw output values of a number of output neurons into probabilities for multi-class classification problems. For binary classification problems, instead of using two output neurons, you use a single output neuron and apply a logistic [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) to the output value. As the sigmoid projects values into the range [0, 1], you get a probability `p`. This is the probability of the current input belonging to one class. The probability of the input belonging to the other class is then `1 - p`.

For your particular case, note that the doc of `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` says:

> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in
>   which each class is independent and not mutually exclusive. For
>   instance, one could perform multilabel classification where a picture
>   can contain both an elephant and a dog at the same time.

From the code you posted I assume that the network has an output dimension larger than one (otherwise the `argmax` makes no sense), probably two. This means that the code actually performs multiple binary classifications, which should be independent -- but you said that it should be a single binary classification.

If my assumptions are correct then the code is wrong because two independent binary classifications are quite different from a single classification problem. In fact, the `y` should have a only single output and you would check whether the probability is `> 0.5` to compare it to the targets.

Comment: Yes I want to classify data into two classes and there are two output neurons. Can you please explain what is meant by independent in your statement "This means that the code actually performs multiple binary classifications, which should be independent".  And what do you mean by mutiple and single binary classification? I have data belonging to 2 different ranges. I label zero to first range and 1 to the second range.

Comment: Moreover Can I infer from your answer that I can't use tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits if I have to use 
    `tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,axis=1),tf.argmax(y_,axis=1))` for checking how accurate is my model

Comment: In a binary classification problem you assign one of 2 classes. In a multiclass problem you assign one of 3 or more classes. In a binary problem you don't need two output neurons because (as I described) you can simply use one neuron and threshold the output instead of having multiple and taking the max. -- And yes, using `tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,axis=1),tf.argmax(y_,axis=1))` makes no sense with `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` (because you are learning independent outputs, not dependent ones like when using softmax).

Comment: You should consider studying the theory of neural networks for classification for a while to get a firm understanding of the concepts.